# Windows Store 10, Windows Phone 10 check if the application is Preloaded or not

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone

Is there any good way to check to see if the application has been pre-loaded on a device or not?

What I need is to be able to check if the user is using the application which is pre-loaded or if he has downloaded it by himself. Is there a property that I can check? or should I ask the OEM to add a file on the devices or properties that I can check?

Answer (score -1):

Try validating the receipt for the app to tell if it was purchased though the store.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219692.aspx

Comment: A receipt is for an in app purchase or when you buy the application on the store, this application is free